# How to produce SSG from a vue project without nuxt

Tags: vue.js, static, server-side-rendering, jamstack, ssg

I created a vue project using the vue cli:

```
vue create myproject
```

I figured that the output when I do `npm run build` will be a single page application (SPA). What do I need to produce a static website (SSG / Jamstack) with my existing code?  I know I could easily do it with Nuxt, but I would like to know how to do it without Nuxt.

EDIT: I think what I meant was to have some of the pages pre-rendered so that it's better for SEO.

Comment: I'm curious to this as well. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the result of your build is a SPA that is static HTML and JS. The user may see dynamic content based on the JS, but it's essentially static and could be deployed to Jamstack hosts like Netlify or Vercel. In other words, unless I'm misreading what you want, there isn't anything special you need to do.

Comment: Hi Raymond, I think what I meant was that the pages are "pre-rendered", so that it's good for SEO.